# How to create symboic link from Azure Linux M to Azure file storage

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, storage

I want to create a symbolic link. the mount point is *Azure Linux VM* and the target is *azure storage*. I have used the following command to create the symbolic link:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<accout name>.file.core.windows.net/<share name> [mount point] -o vers=3.0,username=<username>,password=<pwd>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp
```

But getting following:

```
mount error(11): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`dmesg | tail` gives:

```
CIFS VFS: Server eassmbstorageaccount.file.core.windows.net has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -11
```

Answer (score -1):

We can mount Azure file share to Linux VM like this:
**Ubuntu**:

1.install cifs-utils

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

2.create a folder for the mount point:

```
mkdir mymountpoint
```

3.Use the mount command to mount the Azure file share:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //jasonvmdiag800.file.core.windows.net/jasonvm ./mymountpoint -o vers=2.1,username=jasonvmdiag800,password=t0gU45xhKVlCQZY3L0WYHiEcoyc1vAvKS1FZEgCZpxxrHFRg==,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

Remember to replace `storage-account-name`, `share-name`, and `storage-account-key` with the proper information.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<share-name> ./mymountpoint -o vers=2.1,username=<storage-account-name>,password=<storage-account-key>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

Note:

Azure files share requires **SMB 2**, Microsoft recommends the following Linux distributions:

```
Ubuntu Server 14.04+
RHEL 7+
CentOS 7+
Debian 8
openSUSE 13.2+
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12
```

More information about mount Azure file share, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#install-cifs-utils).

By the way, please check is there another cifs share mounted, and check that share state. Also you can remove all mount files and remount.